# C++: recursive member function template

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I want to write a universal object printer using c++14. The idea is that is searches for `toString()` method in arbitrarily wrapped object. In this example it only understands pointer indirection to get the printable object.

The following code compiles on clang-8, but fails on gcc-9:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct A {
  std::string toString() const { return "gotchA"; }
};

struct Printer {
  void print(const std::string &s) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }

  template <typename T>
  auto print(const T &o) -> std::enable_if_t<
      std::is_same<decltype(o.toString()), std::string>::value> {
    print(o.toString());
  }

  template <typename T> auto print(const T &o) -> decltype(this->print(*o));
};

template <typename T>
auto Printer::print(const T &o) -> decltype(this->print(*o)) {
  print(*o);
}

int main() {
  Printer{}.print(A{});
  Printer{}.print(boost::make_optional(std::make_unique<A>()));
}
```

gcc gives the following error:

```
g++ -std=c++14 recursive.cpp
recursive.cpp:24:6: error: no declaration matches ‘decltype (((Printer*)this)->Printer::print((* o))) Printer::print(const T&)’
   24 | auto Printer::print(const T &o) -> decltype(this->print(*o)) {
      |      ^~~~~~~
recursive.cpp:20:30: note: candidates are: ‘template<class T> decltype (((Printer*)this)->Printer::print((* o))) Printer::print(const T&)’
   20 |   template <typename T> auto print(const T &o) -> decltype(this->print(*o));
      |                              ^~~~~
recursive.cpp:15:8: note:                 ‘template<class T> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype (o.toString()), std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::value> Printer::print(const T&)’
   15 |   auto print(const T &o) -> std::enable_if_t<
      |        ^~~~~
recursive.cpp:12:8: note:                 ‘void Printer::print(const string&)’
   12 |   void print(const std::string &s) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }
      |        ^~~~~
recursive.cpp:11:8: note: ‘struct Printer’ defined here
   11 | struct Printer {
      |        ^~~~~~~
```

as I can see in these compiler output lines, the candidate does not differ from the external definition signature (except for that `template` in the beginning; whitespaces added):

```
recursive.cpp:24:6: error: no declaration matches            ‘decltype (((Printer*)this)->Printer::print((* o))) Printer::print(const T&)’
recursive.cpp:20:30: note: candidates are: ‘template<class T> decltype (((Printer*)this)->Printer::print((* o))) Printer::print(const T&)’
```

How do I achieve the recursion? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: @Peter How is it not declared in the class definition? Additionally, SFINAE should make sure there is only one valid overload when call with for example `std::unique_prt<A>`, no?

Comment: @Peter Normally you can overload identical template signatures as long as only one is valid through SFINAE. In this example, simply removing the class `Printer` and making all the functions free functions will make the code compile for example.

Comment: @Peter [Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uxcYSjRl57vGLwnA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function’s name is not in scope in its own declarator, including any *trailing-return-type*.  As a result, the interpretation of the redeclaration differs from that of the original, because the original is then available.  The [relevant rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link#5) doesn’t make it very clear how to treat cases like this: in particular, the name `print` is not technically a “dependent name” (which are compared as *names* only) because it’s part of a class member access.  (If it is, the recursion shouldn’t work anyway because only the lookup from the first declaration is used.)

The usual approach here is to use a class with partial specializations:

```
template<class> struct Printer;

template<class T>
void print(const T &t) {Printer<T>::go(t);}

template<class T,class=void>
struct Printer {  // recursive case
  void go(const T &t) {print(*t);}
};

template<>
struct Printer<std::string,void> {
  void go(const std::string &s) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }
};

template<class T>
struct Printer<T,std::enable_if_t<
  std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T&>().toString()),
    std::string>::value>> {
  void go(const T &t) {print(t.toString());}
};
```

The last one might be better conditioned merely on the existence of `toString` so that it could make use of the recursive support.